# jquery ui select - how to get reference to original select element

Tags: jquery-ui

Please,
I am using jquery-ui selectmenu and I need to get reference to original `<select>` element from which jquery-ui selectmenu is generated in `_renderMenu` and `_renderItem` methods.
I need to access data about `onchange` events, `classes` ect. to make properly working copy.
So far I didn't find anything in documentation.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Without an example, all I can say is that SelectMenu only hides the original element.

From: http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

If we look at just: `$( "#speed" ).selectmenu();`, and inspect the page you will see:

```
    <label for="speed-button">Select a speed</label>
    <select name="speed" id="speed" style="display: none;">
        <option>Slower</option>
        <option>Slow</option>
        <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
        <option>Fast</option>
        <option>Faster</option>
    </select><span tabindex="0" id="speed-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="speed-menu" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-selectmenu-button-closed ui-corner-all ui-button ui-widget" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Medium</span></span>
```

Here you can see that the original element `#speed` is simply hidden via CSS.

Please review: http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ to see how to access the events.

Comment: sorry, that doesnt fully ansver my question. i found bits in the documentation, but i still struggle with referencing the original element directly. adding an ID and using selectmenu refresh is not ideal at all.

Comment: @Round-Sliced would need to see an example of your code. Please update your post.